# Ignite Nodes disconnects after some time

Tags: ignite

Hi peoples I am facing an issue with my clusters .

Whenever the ignite nodes goes on idle they gets disconnected and after that time if i try to connect my first request gets failed. but after first request all requests are sucessfull until they become idle for some time.

Please help

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context 
with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not 
open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is 
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to communicate with Ignite cluster.] with root 
cause
commons-api_research.1.tmu590s6e7pi@cc-dev-platform03.netlink.com    | 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
commons-api_research.1.tmu590s6e7pi@cc-dev-platform03.netlink.com    |  at 
java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
commons-api_research.1.tmu590s6e7pi@cc-dev-platform03.netlink.com    |  at 
java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
commons-api_research.1.tmu590s6e7pi@cc-dev-platform03.netlink.com    |  at 
java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
commons-api_research.1.tmu590s6e7pi@cc-dev-platform03.netlink.com    |  at 
java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
commons-api_research.1.tmu590s6e7pi@cc-dev-platform03.netlink.com    |  at 
java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
commons-api_research.1.tmu590s6e7pi@cc-dev-platform03.netlink.com    |  at 
 org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.read
```

Comment: Can you provide logs with this error?

Comment: just one exception  "failed to connect with ignite cluster". only on one first request after idle time has expired.

Comment: Please quote all error lines including the stack trace and following reconnect if possible.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its not about DataSource but setting idle connection timeout to max worked for me.

```
TcpCommunicationSpi spi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();

    spi.setUsePairedConnections(true);
    spi.setIdleConnectionTimeout(999999999999999999l);

    cfg.setCommunicationSpi(spi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not keep raw JDBC connections around indefinitely, instead you should use a proper connection pool, such as `c3p0`, with support for connection recycling, etc.

Comment: I am using  org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.Should i use c3p0 or hikari.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe dbcp2 should also work, use setMaxConnLifetimeMillis to avoid having stale connections in the pool (30s should work reasonably well).